# Unity/PlayFab DisplayName 'string' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no accessible extension me accepting a first argument of type 'string'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playfab

I'm not able to print the display name stored in playfab in the settings, reception of the username is enabled, and the user exists but I can't retrieve and print it so that the script fills in the user in the text field I always get this error:

> error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no accessible extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I comment out the line containing the `username.text` the debug prints the username correctly to the console.

```
public void PlayerData()
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetAccountInfo(new GetAccountInfoRequest(
    (result) =>
    {
        Debug.Log(username);
        username.text = result.AccountInfo.Username;
    },
    (error) =>
    {
    Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
    });
}
```

---

Full code PlayFabControler

```
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PlayFab.Json;
using PlayFab.ProfilesModels;
using JsonObject = PlayFab.Json.JsonObject;
using System;


public class PlayFabController : MonoBehaviour 
{


    public static PlayFabController PFC;

    private string userEmail;
    private string userPassword;
    private string username;
    public GameObject loginPanel;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if(PlayFabController.PFC == null)
        {
            PlayFabController.PFC = this;
        }
        else
        {
            if(PlayFabController.PFC != this)
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //Note: Setting title Id here can be skipped if you have set the value in Editor Extensions already.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlayFabSettings.TitleId))
        {
            PlayFabSettings.TitleId = "8741"; // Please change this value to your own titleId from PlayFab Game Manager
        }
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
        //var request = new LoginWithCustomIDRequest { CustomId = "GettingStartedGuide", CreateAccount = true };

        // PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithCustomID(request, OnLoginSuccess, OnLoginFailure);
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("EMAIL"))
        {
            userEmail = PlayerPrefs.GetString("EMAIL");
            userPassword = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PASSWORD");
        var request = new LoginWithEmailAddressRequest { Email = userEmail, Password = userPassword };
        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithEmailAddress(request, OnLoginSuccess, OnLoginFailure);
         
        }
      

    }

    #region Login
    private void OnLoginSuccess(LoginResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Congratulations, you made your first successful API call!");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("EMAIL", userEmail);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PASSWORD", userPassword);
        loginPanel.SetActive(false);
        GetStats();
          //  SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
       

    }
    private void OnRegisterSuccess(RegisterPlayFabUserResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Congratulations, you made your first successful API call!");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("EMAIL", userEmail);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PASSWORD", userPassword);
        GetStats();
        loginPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
    private void OnLoginFailure(PlayFabError error)
    {
        var registerRequest = new RegisterPlayFabUserRequest { Email = userEmail, Password = userPassword, Username = username };
        PlayFabClientAPI.RegisterPlayFabUser(registerRequest, OnRegisterSuccess, OnRegisterFailure);
    }
    private void OnRegisterFailure(PlayFabError error)
    {
        Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }
    public void GetUserEmail(string emailIn)
    {
        userEmail = emailIn;
    }
    public void GetUsername(string usernameIn)
    {
        username = usernameIn; 
    }

    public void GetUserPassword(string passwordIn)
    {
        userPassword = passwordIn;
    }
    public void OnClickLogin()
    {
        var request = new LoginWithEmailAddressRequest { Email = userEmail, Password = userPassword,  };
        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithEmailAddress(request, OnLoginSuccess, OnLoginFailure);
    }
    #endregion Login
    public int playerLevel;
    public int gameLevel;

    public int playerHealth;
    public int playerDamage;

    public int playerHighScore;
    public int playerGolds;


    public void PlayerData()
    {
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetAccountInfo(new GetAccountInfoRequest(),
(result) =>
{
    
    Debug.Log(username);
    //username.text = result.username;
    username = result.AccountInfo.Username;
    
},
(error) =>
{
    Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
});
    }
    #region PlayerStats

    public void SetStats()
    {
        PlayFabClientAPI.UpdatePlayerStatistics(new UpdatePlayerStatisticsRequest{
            // request.Statistics is a list, so multiple StatisticUpdate objects can be defined if required.
            Statistics = new List<StatisticUpdate> {
        new StatisticUpdate { StatisticName = "PlayerLevel", Value = playerLevel },
        new StatisticUpdate { StatisticName = "GameLevel", Value = gameLevel },
        new StatisticUpdate { StatisticName = "PlayerHealth", Value = playerHealth },
        new StatisticUpdate { StatisticName = "PlayerDamage", Value = playerDamage },
        new StatisticUpdate { StatisticName = "PlayerHighScore", Value = playerHighScore },
        new StatisticUpdate { StatisticName = "PlayerGolds", Value = playerGolds },
    }
        },
    result => { Debug.Log("User statistics updated"); },
    error => { Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport()); });
    }


    void GetStats()
    {
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetPlayerStatistics(
            new GetPlayerStatisticsRequest(),
            OnGetStats,
            error => Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport())
        );
    }

    void OnGetStats(GetPlayerStatisticsResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Received the following Statistics:");
        foreach (var eachStat in result.Statistics)
        {
            Debug.Log("Statistic (" + eachStat.StatisticName + "): " + eachStat.Value);
            switch(eachStat.StatisticName)
            {
                case "PlayerLevel":
                    playerLevel = eachStat.Value;
                    break;

                case "GameLevel":
                    gameLevel = eachStat.Value;
                    break;
                case "PlayerHealth":
                    playerHealth = eachStat.Value;
                    break;
                case "PlayerDamage":
                    playerDamage = eachStat.Value;
                    break;
                case "PlayerHighScore":
                    playerHighScore = eachStat.Value;
                    break;
                case "PlayerGolds":
                    playerGolds = eachStat.Value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Build the request object and access the API
   public void StartCloudUpdatePlayerStats()
    {
        PlayFabClientAPI.ExecuteCloudScript(new ExecuteCloudScriptRequest()
        {
            FunctionName = "UpdatePlayerStats", // Arbitrary function name (must exist in your uploaded cloud.js file)
            FunctionParameter = new { Level = playerLevel, GameLevel = gameLevel, Health = playerHealth, Damage = playerDamage, highScore = playerHighScore, Golds = playerGolds },
            GeneratePlayStreamEvent = true, // Optional - Shows this event in PlayStream
        }, OnCloudUpdateStats, OnErrorShared);
    }
    // OnCloudHelloWorld defined in the next code block

    private static void OnCloudUpdateStats(ExecuteCloudScriptResult result)
    {
        // CloudScript (Legacy) returns arbitrary results, so you have to evaluate them one step and one parameter at a time
        
        JsonObject jsonResult = (JsonObject)result.FunctionResult;
        object messageValue;
        jsonResult.TryGetValue("messageValue", out messageValue); // note how "messageValue" directly corresponds to the JSON values set in CloudScript (Legacy)
        Debug.Log((string)messageValue);
    }

    private static void OnErrorShared(PlayFabError error)
    {
        Debug.Log(error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }
    #endregion PlayerStats
}
```

Comment: If `username` is a `string`, as the error message states, then it has no `text` member. You might consider a [mcve] so we can see a clearer picture of what you're doing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Hi thanks for your reply added full code for more help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Username is a string so just drop the .text  however im sure you want to assign that string to some form of visible text on a canvas somewhere in your scene.

Comment: @BugFinder Hi, thanks for your reply, yes exactly I wanted to assign it to a textfield. but i have this error.

Comment: So you need a variable for the type of textbox. Then maybe you can do my_textbox.text depending on the type of textbox